# Rails s and rails console not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, terminal

I haven't used Ruby in a while, so I just came back to it today and whenever I try to do rails s or rails console it spits out the generic help text, i.e.

```
    rails console                                                  ~
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                 # Default: /Users/cabelhigh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]        # Path to a application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]      # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile]           # Don't create a Gemfile
      [--skip-bundle]            # Don't run bundle install
```

It just does this over and over. Any idea what's wrong?

Also, I'm running OSX, if that has anything to do with it.

EDIT: Version info: Rails 3.2.8, ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]

Comment: Please post your version information (rails and ruby).

Comment: Did so. Now in the original post.

Comment: are you in the right directory?

Comment: Urg I am dumb. Sorry for this stupid question! It's been a while with rails for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not in a rails application directory when you execute the commands

Make a new rails app with

```
rails new blog
```

cd into the directory

```
cd blog
```

and run

```
rails s
```

or

```
rails c
```

Answer (score 0):

`rails console` works only in Rails project directory

Answer (score 0):

Rails console work only in rails project directory.

May be you want run ruby console? (like irb, pry, etc)